# Why is the argument to malloc i+1 in this C code?

Tags: c, malloc

Usually a malloc contains `sizeof` , but this one doesn't and has i+1 instead:

```
int main ()
{
  int i,n;
  char * buffer;

  printf ("How long do you want the string? ");
  scanf ("%d", &i);

  buffer = (char*) malloc (i+1);
  if (buffer==NULL) exit (1);
```

Comment: Not to mention that you shouldn't really cast the return value of `malloc`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you wanted to allocate an array of some type, you would normally multiply the number of elements you wanted by the size of that type, because `malloc` takes the size of the array in *bytes*.

However, an array of `char` is a special case; you do not need to multiply the number of elements you want by `sizeof(char)`, because `sizeof(char)` is defined by the Standard to *always* be `1`, and multiplication by 1 yields the other operand.

The `+ 1` is to make room for the `NUL` terminator. If you want a string of length `n`, your array has to be of length `n + 1`; `n` spaces for the `n` characters of the string, and `1` space for the terminator.

By the way, you shouldn't cast the return value of `malloc`. It will make your code easier to change in the future.

Comment: I understand now, so char is just 1 byte and the +1 is NULL. Thank You Very Much!

Comment: Byte *packData = (Byte *)calloc(byteLen, sizeof(Byte));
Does this code needs byteLen + 1?

Comment: What if the +1 is omitted? What could be the potential downside or issue when copying strings?

Answer (score 3):

C strings are null-terminated, see:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string

E.g. "abc" is represented as "abc" + NUL. Thus, for a string of length `i`, you need to allocate `i + 1`. As you are allocating chars, sizeof(char) is 1, so you actually need to allocate `1 * (i + 1)`, but that's the same.

Answer (score 2):

If its allocating for a string you need enough memory for the number of characters + 1 extra for the null character that denotes the end of the string (\0)